# How to convert json array to collection with System.Text.Json;

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a `User` class that has a property `Roles` of type `ISet<Role>`, where `Role` is an `enum` type. In JSON I get an array for that property (`"Roles":["Admin","User"]`, for example). How can I write a custom converter to convert this array into `ISet` collection?

I've tried to write this class:

```
class CustomStringToRoleConverter : JsonConverter<ISet<User.Role>> {
    public override ISet<User.Role> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ISet<User.Role> roles, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(string.Join(",", roles.Select(role => role.ToString()).ToArray()));
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        writer.WriteStringValue(builder.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

but I don't know what to do in `Read` method. How do I get the array from `Utf8JsonReader`? There is a `GetString` method, but it throws exception when I call it:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type
> 'StartArray' as a string.

I am using `System.Text` and `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: I would create the data structure and create my own parse function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON `"Roles":["Admin","User"]` property is an array of string values, not a single string value containing comma-separated values.  Thus the easiest way to write your custom converter is as follows:

```
class CustomStringToRoleConverter : JsonConverter<ISet<User.Role>> {
    public override ISet<User.Role> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(ref reader, options)
            ?.Select(s => Enum.Parse<User.Role>(s))
            ?.ToHashSet(); // Or use a SortedSet if you prefer

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ISet<User.Role> roles, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, roles.Select(r => r.ToString()), options);
}
```

The converter simply serializes and deserializes a collection of strings, then parses or formats the items to the `Role` enum as a post- or pre-processing step.  (For comparison, your existing `Write()` method would generate `"Roles": ["Admin,User"]` which does not match the JSON shown in the starting paragraph of your question.)

Sample fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nzvn1d).

If you are very concerned with performance and would prefer a more "manual" approach that does not deserialize to an intermediate `List<string>`, you could do:

```
class CustomStringToRoleConverter : JsonConverter<ISet<User.Role>> {
    public override ISet<User.Role> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null)
            return null; // Or throw an exception if you don't want to allow null
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            throw new JsonException();
        var set = new HashSet<User.Role>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                return set;
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
                set.Add(Enum.Parse<User.Role>(reader.GetString()));
            else
            {
                //reader.Skip();
                throw new JsonException(); // Unexpected token;
            }
        }
        throw new JsonException(); // Truncated file;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ISet<User.Role> roles, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var value in roles)
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Sample fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VRj9kp).

Alternatively, you could simply add [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=net-5.0) to [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters?view=net-5.0) to serialize all enums as strings.